# How to place multiple form elements from a loop

Tags: forms

I have a table that will have multiple table rows that are generated dynamically using a foreach loop. In these rows will be textfields using the Drupal forms API.

Example:

```
$f = '<table>';
$f .= '<tr><td>Something...</td></tr>';

foreach($somethingAwesome as $val){
    $f .= '<tr><td>';

    $form['blah'][$val] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
    );

    $f .= '</td></tr>';
}

$f .= '<tr><td>Something else...</td></tr>';
$f .= '</table>';

$form['woot'] = array(
    '#type' => 'whatever',
    '#prefix' => $f
);
```

This winds up outputting the form elements after the table in the page. This is not what I am expecting.

The output looks something like:

```
Something...
Something else...

Textfield
Textfield
(etc...)
```

It should look like this:

```
Something...

Textfield
Textfield
(etc...)

Something else...
```

I have tried using the #prefix in the textfield form elements but that produces some odd unexpected (at least for me) behavior.

I am using Drupal 7, if that makes any difference.

Edit: Added that I am in fact adding the $val to the $form element in the foreach loop

Comment: Sorry I thought I had "Drupal 7" in the title. I am sure of it... was it stripped out? Either way, thank you for the edit @kiamlaluno

Comment: It was in the title; I removed it because the answers are not specific for Drupal 7. Putting "Drupal 7" in the title would make future readers think the answers are specifically for Drupal 7.

Comment: Ah, yes... makes perfect sense. Thank you for that insight.

Comment: @kiamlaluno that seems like the perfect thing to put in the [faq] ;-)

Comment: @Chapabu [Should I not be putting Drupal 7 in question titles?](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-i-not-be-putting-drupal-7-in-question-titles/203#203) `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno lol...well..that's awfully embarrassing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if I understand correctly:

```
$header = '<table>';
$header .= '<tr><td>Something...</td></tr>';

$form['header'] = array(
  '#markup' => $header;
)

$i = 1;

foreach($somethingAwesome as $val){

    $form['blah_' . $i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield';
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>'
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
    );

$i++;
}

$footer = '<tr><td>Something else...</td></tr>';
$footer .= '</table>';

$form['footer'] = array(
    '#markup' => $footer,
);
```

This should give you the output:

Something...

TEXTFIELD
TEXTFIELD
TEXTFIELD

Something else...

You'll need to do something to differentiate each `$form['blah']` part too, otherwise you'll be running a `foreach` loop that overwrites that specific part of your form on every iteration.

You're running your `foreach` loop in the place where you *want* it, but all of the data you want surrounding the form is being put into one variable, and then added in one go as a prefix.  Suffix will add data to the end.

**General Reference (in case you didn't know):**

[FormAPI Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

**Specific References:**

[#prefix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix)

[#suffix](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix)

Comment: That is how I am doing some other stuff and it works for sure. However, where would I put $f so that it is output?

Comment: Aaah...I see what you're trying to do!  Give me 5 minutes and I'll edit my answer!

Comment: I *think* that should work.  You mentioned using `#prefix` gave odd results - hopefully using `#suffix` as well should rectify this.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It outputs the form and *then* the textfields just as before, except this time it puts all the stuff within the foreach loop together. That is a positive change lol

Comment: lol...oh dear.  I think the answer I provided earlier may actually still apply you know.  Other than that I'll have to come back to this tomorrow morning unless someone gets here in between.  I'm really sorry.  One more edit before bed :p

Comment: I **WILL** get this to work lol Thank you for all your help! :)